# Converting List<int> to List<String> in flutter?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, sharedpreferences

I have a integar list like `[1,2,3,4]` and I a need to make a new list as a String list like `['1','2','3','4']`, how can I convert it easily? I need to do this for using Sharedpreferences getStringList command.

```
List<int> selectedAmount = [];
IconButton(
   onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BodyPage(goal: widget.goal)));
    waterAmount = amount[index];
    print(' secilen = $waterAmount');
    selectedAmount.add(waterAmount);
    setState(() => this.index = index);},
     icon: Icon(
     Icons.add,
     size: 28,
     color: Colors.blueGrey,))
```

and the other page:

```
  List<int> totalList = selectedAmount;


List<String> totalStringList = totalList.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
```

"The instance member 'totalList' can't be accessed in an initializer." im getting this error.

Comment: Welcome, please Post what have you tried so far

Comment: You need to put the line that maps the integer list to the string list in the constructor of the second page. It has to be inside of a method.

Comment: it worked, thanks! my problem was setting a variable outside at the method, I set it on initState and that works for me :-) cool

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do so is

```
List<int> numbers = <int>[1,2,3,4];
  final List<String> strs = numbers.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
  print(strs);
```

You can check the type of List in runtime by

```
print(strs.runtimeType);
```

Comment: im gettin an error "The instance member 'totalList' can't be accessed in an initializer." :(

Comment: You need to share your code. So, we can help you to change your code. Because this code is working for me.

Comment: im new at this forum, i sheared my code, thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You can use map()

```
List<String> stringList = intList.map((element) => el.toString()).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue whilst avoiding your issue, it's probably easiest to use:

```dart
List<String> get totalStringList => totalList.map((e) => e.toString()).toList();
```

This uses a getter, which does not have the same limitations as a normal variable.

Note that you won't be able to set (write to) this variable, but using it's value will work exactly the same as any other variable.

Comment: that's a another useful method, thank you very much!